# Stop the handler inside itself

Tags: android

I am trying to stop the Handler inside the handler self but I am getting this error. How can I stop the Handler in this case?

> Cannot instantiate the type Runnable

**Code:**

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    senseWiFi();
                    if(WIFINumberList.size() > 1){
                        int first = WIFINumberList.get(0);
                        int second = WIFINumberList.get(1);
                        if(first == second){
                            route_number = first;
                            System.out.println("route equal route_number.");
                       //Here I mam getting the error.
                            new Handler().removeCallbacks(new Runnable());
                        }else{
                            System.out.println("route equal ZERO.");
                        }

                    }
                }
            }, 1*30 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
new Handler().removeCallbacks(new Runnable());
```

Means creating new object of `Handler`  and for removing callback from `Handler` passing new object of `Runnable`.

Instead of this create a separate object of Handler and `Runnable` like:

```
Handler handler=new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(runnable);
Runnable runnable =new Runnable() {
      @Override
       public void run() {
        // your code here
        //remove callback here
      handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
     }
}
```

means use same object of both Handler and Runnable which is used for calling `postDelayed` method instead of creating new Object

Comment: I had to double check but seems that handlers use queue from the looper they're associated with, which would mean that technically creating a new Handler and calling `removeCallbacks` should work. I do prefer your way of doing it though, but you have a couple of mistakes there: the handler needs to be *final* and you're creating the runnable after using it ;)

Comment: @Zharf: `Handler need to final` when it is declare inside a method but if you declare it at class level and initilizing inside any method then no need to make it final

Comment: True, your answer is a bit unclear on what's around the code.